# Robot Framework : Error WebDriverException on executing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I enter the text into test area and save then I click on Edit button now i have to remove the text from textbox.

I am getting error when i execute the below command for clearing textbox.

```
`Execute Javascript    window.document.getElementByName('resolution').value='';`
```

HTML:

```
<span class="textarea-text edit" sfuuid="1832">
<textarea class="input-xlarge wide tleft" name="resolution" cols="" rows="">test</textarea>
<p class="help-block"></p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a textarea tag not a **input** tag with value attribute. You can clearly see that your **textarea**. Doesn't have a value attribute. The text  "test" is the innerHTML of the element so try setting the innerHTML

LIKE

document.getElementById("").innerHTML=' '

Answer (score 0):

Names are not necessarily unique. Thus, there is no getElementByName method. It is getElementsByName (note the plurality). If you want to just try your operation on the first element found in the DOM with that name, change your code to:

```
Execute Javascript    window.document.getElementsByName('resolution')[0].value='';
```

Note that it is not necessary to use JavaScript to accomplish this either. Instead, you could do:

```
Input Text    name=resolution    ${EMPTY}
```